# How to insert multiple textfield?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on a project for school.
It's an invoice program but I'm stuck, can anyone help me
figure out how to get the values out of multiple textboxes /fields
and insert them in to my database.
This is what it looks like.
The user can select the amount of textfields that will be inserted in to the database.

[IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/2sagwt4.png[/IMG]

Comment: You can loop trouch $_POST value, or give some name to the textfield tag  as example.

Comment: Do you have an example

Comment: The standard response is: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have product, Product description, quantity and the price this is my html form field and I have 15 of these forms. In my php script i have this [code]foreach($_POST["Product"] as $key => $text_field){
 //query insert for product     
}[/code]

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: foreach($_POST["Product"] as $key => $text_field){ //query insert for product }

Answer (score 0):

Easy example:

```
       <?php
$host=''; //define host
$user='xxx'; //define username
$pass='xxx'; //define password
$db_name='xxx'; //define db name
$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['status'])) { //code called when user sent form
    $status = mysqli_escape_string($db, ($_POST['status']));
    //same way to save other fields, just rename "status" to your value

    $sql = "INSERT INTO /* table name here */ (status, /* define other line in DB here */) VALUES ('$status', /* define other variables to save here */)"; //save into database, see the example below
    //example: $sql = "INSERT INTO mydatabase (status, email, name) VALUES ('$status', '$email', '$name')";
    if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "Saved.";
                }
                else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }
}
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
<label for="status">Status: </label>
<input id="status" name="status" value="" />
//add other fields here, just rename "status" to your value

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send form" /></form>
```

It may be what you are looking for, just adapt it yourself.

Comment: tanks but it is not what I'm looking for